# Commands in "private void WON_SelectionChanged" not executed

Tags: c#

I am making a plugin application that will work in a third party program in C#. Unfortunately I can not debug my code when inside the program.
It is an application where the user selects items from pull down lists and when certain combinations are selected others are excluded etc.
In one of the pull down menus though, when I select a certain number some commands are executed but others are not for no apparent reason(for me who I am a novice, maybe for you it would be so obvious).

```
private void WON_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DesignNo.IsEnabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Selection Changed!!!");
    string contentStr = (WON.SelectedItem ?? string.Empty).ToString();
    //If AK89 is selected then the WONItem numbers have to change to 14 
    if (string.Equals("AK89", contentStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("IN AK89!!!");
        this.WONitem.Items.Clear();
        WONitem.Items.Add("-1");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-2");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-3");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-4");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-5");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-6");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-7");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-8");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-9");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-10");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-11");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-12");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-13");
        WONitem.Items.Add("-14");
        WONitem.SelectedIndex = WONitem.Items.Count - 14;

    }
    // Disable the ones done.
    //
    //contentStr = (this.WON.SelectedItem ?? string.Empty).ToString();
    //MessageBox.Show("IN AK85!!!" + contentStr);
    if (string.Equals("AK85", contentStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {

        contentStr = (this.DesignNo.SelectedItem ?? string.Empty).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("IN AK85!!!" + contentStr);
        if (string.Equals(" 100019646-2", contentStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IN the drawingNo 100019646-2!!!");
            DesignNo.Items.Clear();
            WONitem.Items.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("should be cleared now!!!");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-9");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-10");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-11");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-12");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-13");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-14");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-15");
            WONitem.Items.Add("-16");
            WONitem.SelectedIndex = WONitem.Items.Count - 8;
        }
        else if (string.Equals(" 100019646-1", contentStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //contentStr = (this.DesignNo.SelectedItem ?? string.Empty).ToString();
            //if (string.Equals(" 100019646-1", contentStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

                MessageBox.Show("IN the drawingNo 100019646-1!!!");
                this.WONitem.Items.Clear();
                WONitem.Items.Add("-9");
                WONitem.Items.Add("-10");
                WONitem.Items.Add("-11");
                WONitem.Items.Add("-12");
                WONitem.Items.Add("-13");
                WONitem.Items.Add("-14");
                WONitem.Items.Add("-15");
                WONitem.Items.Add("-16");
                WONitem.SelectedIndex = WONitem.Items.Count - 8;
        }
        else
            {

            }

    }


    DesignNo.IsEnabled = false;
```

When WON equals to AK89 then WONitem changes successfully the WONitems to 14.
When WON equals to AK85 and DesignNO equals to " 100019646-2" I can see that the message (I have placed all these messages so I know which command gets executed in the program)
"IN AK85!!! AK85" then the message "IN the drawingNo 100019646-2!!!" pops up but the next commands will not get executed and also the message
MessageBox.Show("should be cleared now!!!");
Never comes up!

I am stuck. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was me (as always is).

I had to replace my comparison with string.Compare. I had some spaces and dashes that were not liked at all in my string. Anyway string.Compare did the job.

The code is below.

```
contentStr = (this.DesignNo.SelectedItem ?? string.Empty).ToString();

            string compareWith = " 100019406-2";

            int compareResult = string.Compare(contentStr, compareWith);

            if (compareResult == 1)
```